# How do I GET data from Firebase using my id instead of the Firebase unique ID?

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a basic todo list and store it in Firebase and then access it with a REST API.

I have successfully inserted my data into the database, however, I am unable to query it via the ID of my JSON and not the ID that Firebase assigns to it.

This works, and returns all the JSON:

```
https://nicktodo-<blah>.firebaseio.com/todos.json
```

That returns a lovely chunk of JSON.

However, when I call:

```
https://nicktodo-<blah>.firebaseio.com/todos/id/20.json
```

which I think should return the item in my JSON file with id: 20, I get a `null` return.

I can see that my data is in there, because this:

```
https://nicktodo-<blah>.firebaseio.com/todos/0.json
```

returns the JSON for the first element in my data.

```
{
    "complete": true,
    "editMode": false,
    "id": 20,
    "note": "This is a note for 20",
    "title": "Clean the bathroom"
}
```

I don't want to use the Firebase-generated ID's, I want to use my IDs.

I have read the documentation, and it leads me to believe that my queries above should work.

Is there a way that I am missing to put my data into the database that doesn't use the generated id's?

Is there a way to proper way to query the data that doesn't involve the id's generated by Firebase?

**EDIT**: I'd actually be happy to use the generated ID's if I could find a way to return them